# Use global variable from another file in an imported class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two files:

**file1.py**

```py
class A:
    def test(self):
        return LIST[0]
```

**file2.py**

```py
from file1 import A

LIST = ['+', '%', '$']
a = A()

a.test()
```

When I run **file2.py** it returns:

> `NameError: name 'LIST' is not defined`

Ideally it would return:

> `'+'`

How can I use the global variable defined in **file2.py** in my class defined in **file1.py** and imported into **file2.py**?

(I think I need to do it this way, because I want all changes to `LIST` to be reflected for every object... is there a better way?)

Comment: It would be a much better idea to change your code to not do this. Have `test` take an argument.

Comment: Another option would be to have the constructor of `A` take an argument.

Comment: Unless you need `LIST` in `file2.py`, just define it in `file1.py`. If you genuinely need it in both modules, just `import` it.

Comment: Absolutely there is a better way, don't rely on global mutable state. That is a well-known anti-pattern. Instead, explicitly pass arguments to functions, or alternatively, use a class to encapsulate state (in this case, with a class variable if you want it to be shared by all `A` objects)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file, like `utils.py`, and in it put `LIST` (or if you don't want to add an extra file, you could take on circular dependencies). Then you could import it in the files you want to. Alternatively, you could pass it as a constructor argument, which would be a much better solution.

Answer (score 0):

> (I think I need to do it this way, because I want all changes to LIST to be reflected for every object... is there a better way?)

You can try a making a class method, which changes the constants of a class
https://stackabuse.com/pythons-classmethod-and-staticmethod-explained/
So if you write a class like this
file1.py

```py
class A:
    LIST = "whatever"
    def test(self):
        return self.LIST[0]

    @classmethod
    def updateList(cls, val):
        cls.LIST = val
```

such that in file2, your code can look like this

```py
from file1 import A

A.updateList(['+', '%', '$'])
a = A()

print(a.test())
```

should print

```
+
```